# How to add a mouselistener to images which are inserted using graph.drawimage()?

Tags: java, graphic

```
    public class buttonActionStart implements ActionListener {      // overwritten ActionListener

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        JFrame window2 = new JFrame("Main Game"); //create empty frame

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        window2.setSize(screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
        window2.add(new JPanel(){

        public void paintComponent(Graphics graph){
            super.paintComponent(graph);

            Board board = new Board();

            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[1].getName(),440,560);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[2].getName(),335,560);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[3].getName(),225,560);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[4].getName(),145,560);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[5].getName(),30,560);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[6].getName(),25,460);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[7].getName(),25,360);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[8].getName(),35,260);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[9].getName(),25,160);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[10].getName(),25,60);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[11].getName(),140,60);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[12].getName(),240,60);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[13].getName(),340,60);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[14].getName(),440,60);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[15].getName(),530,60);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[16].getName(),550,160);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[17].getName(),545,260);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[18].getName(),540,360);
            graph.drawString(board.sqaures[19].getName(),550,460);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                graph.drawRect(10 + (i*100),10,100,100);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                graph.drawRect(10,110 + (j*100),100,100);
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                graph.drawRect(510,110 + (k*100),100,100);
            for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
                graph.drawRect(10 + (l*100),510,100,100);

            InputStream resource = UI.class.getResourceAsStream("player1.png");
            Image player1Image = null;
            try{
                player1Image = ImageIO.read(resource);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            resource = UI.class.getResourceAsStream("player2.png");
            Image player2Image = null;
            try{
                player2Image = ImageIO.read(resource);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            resource = UI.class.getResourceAsStream("player3.png");
            Image player3Image = null;
            try{
                player3Image = ImageIO.read(resource);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            resource = UI.class.getResourceAsStream("player4.png");
            Image player4Image = null;
            try{
                player4Image = ImageIO.read(resource);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            graph.drawImage(player1Image, 511, 511, null);
            graph.drawImage(player2Image, 585, 510, null);
            graph.drawImage(player3Image, 511, 585, null);
            graph.drawImage(player4Image, 585, 585, null);
            }
        });
        window2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am developing a kind of board game and these four images will serve as the player icon. I want the player to click the image which is assigned to them manually, then click somewhere else on the screen and the image will be "updated" to that position.

The "square" and board" will be my self-defined class.

I got another window which will have a "start" button and triggering the above graphic to be drawn on a new window.

I do found a lot of people suggesting to add image using JLabel and add the JLabel to the JFrame but I found that the image will cover my graphic.

Comment: For [deity] name: stop reading the images in `paintComponent` - your experience will be an extreme slow motion. Read the once, paint them afterwards as many times as you want, but stop reading them every time the component need painred!!!

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more? I don't quite get what you mean. Do you mean it is bad way to read image in paintComponent()? I want to further ask that do I need to add the JLabel to a JPanel before adding the JLabel directly to the JFrame?

Comment: `Do you mean it is bad way to read image in paintComponent()?` - yes. A painting method is for painting only and for nothing else. Images should be read in the constructor of your class so they are only read once when the class is created. So don't create the Board class either.

Comment: Appreciate ur advice, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Do as suggested and use a JLabel. By saying "the image will cover my graphics", you probably mean that transparent parts of the image will not show the background. If so, call `JLabel.setOpaque(false)`.
2. Add a MouseListener to the component for which you implement the `paintComponent()` method (probably a JFrame implementation). You will then get mouse events whenever the user clicks into the component. In the listener implementation, you then have to manually check whether the coordinates fall into the area of one of the images.

Generally speaking, for a game I would prefer option 2: You use a blank canvas and draw your game scene into the canvas. User interactions are then managed by a general game logic object which delegates to game objects such as 'player', 'NPC', etc., based on the coordinates / pressed keys / etc.

Comment: What do you mean the transparent part? I mean, my image is quite small (25*25 just like a little icon). Do you mean the unoccupied place in the JLabel?

Comment: I assumed that your image has transparent pixels. If it hasn't, and more than just the image area is covered when using a JLabel, then the size of the JLabel is set wrong by the LayoutManager. In that case, look into Java Swing layout and how to use LayoutManagers, so that the JLabel is not resized to be larger than its preferred size.

If you don't know what this means, please create a minimal example of your version with a JLabel and post another SO question for that example.

Comment: A JLabel is non-opaque by default.

Comment: @camickr Oops, you are absolutely right! Sorry for the confusion. So it's not the opacity, but the layout of the JLabels which seems to be the problem here.